# SharePoint 2010 Language Pack

Tags: 2010, service-applications, multilingual

We are planning to install more than one language packs in SharePoint Server 2010(Enterprise).

I wanted to know whether we need to install each and every language pack having SP1(Language Pack SP1) separately or only one SP1 for all language packs? Kindly confirm.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you need to install just one SP1 for all the language packs. You can download the SP1 from [Microsoft Site](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26621)

Comment: I think have to download and install each language pack separate SP1..Kindly visit url http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26621

Comment: No. Starting Aug-2008, do not remember the date correctly, all language packs are cumulative and contains updates for all languages.